# Git: How do you checkout all deleted files?

Tags: git, version-control, git-checkout, configuration-management

In git I am familiar with how to checkout individual files that have been deleted using the `git checkout -- [<paths>...]` syntax (which is recommended when you do `git status`.

To get all the files you could create a list and give the list as the argument to the above command.

However when you just want all the files that have been deleted (i.e. rm -rf in your cwd and then you want to restore all files) generating that list is inelegant.

**How do you checkout all deleted files?**

Comment: I added what I usually do to clear untrack files in my answer below. It is very handy most cases after a `git reset --hard` :)

Answer (score 26):

Generating the list is not *that* hard:

```
git diff --no-renames --name-only --diff-filter=D
```

To make it suitable for `git checkout`, use `-z` and `xargs -0`:

```
git diff --no-renames --name-only --diff-filter=D -z |
    xargs -0 git checkout --
```

Note that using `git checkout -f -- .` is quite different from the above, as `git checkout -f -- .` will overwrite files that are modified but not yet added to the index, while the above will *only* extract, from the index, files that are *still in* the index but are no longer in the work-tree.

(If you have no such modified files, `git checkout -f -- .` will work, but then so will `git checkout -- .`.)

Comment: To find deleted files, use filter=D, not filter=R

Comment: @Oli: oops, yes, yikes!

Comment: So to checkout the deleted files: `git checkout $(git diff --no-renames --name-only --diff-filter=D)`

Comment: @ArturKlesun: yes, provided the file names don't have white-space in them (if they do you need to do something fancier to keep the shell from treating `this file name has spaces` as naming five files named `this` and `file` and so on.)

Comment: @torek, you could just start the answer with `git checkout -- .` (though I wonder if it's recursive)

Comment: @Pacerier: it is recursive, but the issue here is that the question asks to check out only *deleted* files. Running `git checkout -- .` will copy the index version of each file out, erasing all the work you did in any un-`git add`-ed files. (This is all a little bit clearer when using the new `git restore` command that first appeared in Git version 2.23. There is a "safe" `git checkout`, which is now available as `git switch`, and a "destroy all my work if I'm not careful" `git checkout`, which is now `git restore`.)

Answer (score 12):

> when you just want all the files that have been deleted (i.e. rm -rf in your cwd and then you want to restore all files)

You want

```
git checkout-index -a
```

Answer (score 6):

I usually do a

```
git checkout .
```

to checkout changes followed by

```
git clean -fd
```

This would remove untrack files. `f` for files and `d` for directories.

You could do also do a dry run prior to 2nd step by doing

```
git clean -fdn
```

This would list down files and directories to be deleted.

Please refer more info on [undoing changes](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-clean/)

Answer (score 2):

If the changes for delete files has not committed, you can use `git checkout -- .`.

If the changes for delete files has been committed, you can use `git reset --hard HEAD~`.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it with:

```
for f in $(git diff --no-renames --name-only --diff-filter=D);do git checkout -- $f ;done
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `git checkout --force` seems to do the trick. The man page for the `--force` option says "[The --force option] is used to throw away local changes".

From the `git-checkout` man page:

```
   -f, --force
       When switching branches, proceed even if the index or the
       working tree differs from HEAD. This is used to throw away 
       local changes.

       When checking out paths from the index, do not fail upon 
       unmerged entries; instead, unmerged entries are ignored.
```