# Git: How to checkout all deleted files through whole history

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-log

I want to restore all deleted files through whole history, which means to checkout  files to the commit before the commit that delete it?

Comment: Hi. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Mehdi I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41593424/git-how-do-you-checkout-all-deleted-files, which apply to just one commit

Comment: @bilabila Are you *searching* for a specific file in all this list? Or do you need the actual list?

Answer (score 3):

Within a bash context*, you can get a **sorted list of all deleted files from your repo** with

```
git log --all --diff-filter=D --name-only --pretty=format:'' | sort | uniq
```

where

`--all` means log all commits, regardless of the current position of `HEAD`

`--diff-filter=D` filters displayed commits along this condition : "`D`", meaning "deleted"

`--name-only` outputs the names of the files

`--pretty=format:''` shuts down any other output than file names

and the git command then formed returns a list which is sent to

`| sort` to sort the list alphabetically, and then

`| uniq` to keep only one instance for each doubled line (or else a file deleted then re-created then re-deleted would appear twice in the list)

---

Of course, you might also want to restrict the range to take into account for the history traversal. If you need only commits which were deleted from, let's say, branch `super-feature`, add that as the `<revision range>` for log (see [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)) which, when omitted, falls back to `HEAD` :

```
git log --all --diff-filter=D --name-only --pretty=format:'' master..super-feature | sort | uniq
```

---

* *(either natively on linux-based systems, or for Windows users in GitBash for example)*